# Copy file to an output directory to another project's output dir

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a project using selenium. I would like to use it as a library. To open chrome browser (using client project) I need path to chromedriver.exe which is inside library. Any way to copy it to target project when someone reference to it?

Thanks.

Comment: I added this file to project (and set to copy to output directory) but when i update it by a nuget I will probably forget to update this file. So now the second question is. How to update it automatically?

Comment: Added chromedriver.exe as link but then I get it copied with the whole folder structure. This solves the problem with updates but destroys structure for client's code.